# Altering data type and default on DB2 LUW 10.5

Tags: alter-table, db2-luw

I am trying to do 2 alters to a column in DB2 in the same alter command, and it doesn't seem to like my syntax. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

```
create table tbl(col varchar(10))
```

The following works, using 2 alter statements:

```
alter table tbl
alter column col set data type varchar(128)

alter table tbl
alter column col set default current user
```

The following attempts fail:

```
alter table tbl
alter column col set data type varchar(128) set default current user
```

> An unexpected token "set data type varchar(128)" was found following
>   "TBL alter column col".  Expected tokens may include:  ""..
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.67.28

```
alter table tbl
alter column col set data type varchar(128) with default current user
```

> An unexpected token "data type varchar(128)" was found following
>   "alter column col set".  Expected tokens may include:  ""..
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.67.28

```
alter table tbl
alter column col set data type varchar(128) 
alter column col set default current user
```

> "COL" is a duplicate name.. SQLCODE=-612, SQLSTATE=42711,
>   DRIVER=3.67.28

Comment: You cannot alter the same column twice in the same statement -- that's what SQLCODE -612 is telling you. Your other attempts are syntactically incorrect.

Comment: As per http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00612n.html a column name can only be referenced in one ADD, DROP COLUMN, or ALTER COLUMN clause in a single ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: @GeekyDaddy that seems to answer the question; why not list it as an answer?

Comment: I was just re-emphasizing @mustaccio response and providing the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot alter the same column twice in the same statement -- that's what SQLCODE -612 is telling you. As per http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00612n.html

> a column name can only be referenced in one ADD, DROP COLUMN, or ALTER COLUMN clause in a single ALTER TABLE statement.

The other attempts are syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table tbl 
alter COLUMN col set DATA TYPE VARCHAR(128)
ALTER column B SET DEFAULT current user;
```

Comment: What did you change in the query and why does it solve the problem?